# Issue Signing xap file in post build event on TFS Build

Tags: silverlight, tfs, continuous-integration, code-signing

We have a silverlight(5) project, the source in TFS (2010) and Continuous Integration build has been setup and working fine. However, we are now at the stage where we are trying to release it to some users to get them using it and give feedback. I've set up the code so that it checks for updates and if there are any it downloads the latest xap file. However this requires the xap file to be signed. No problem when doing this from our dev machines, but when it comes to the automated build it fails, with the message

> Xap packaging failed. Cannot locate the signing tool SignTool.exe.

I've tried numerous things to get the signtool to be recoginised and can't. However, we don't actually need this on the CI build, so I've then tried a second tack which is to make the postbuild event conditional on being run in VisualStudio. Followed various suggestions here on SO but can't gett them to work.

The post build event is

```
    if "$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)" == "true" (
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /f "$(SolutionDir)castle.pfx" "$(TargetDir)Castle.xap"
copy "$(TargetDir)Castle.xap" "$(SolutionDir)Castle.Web\ClientBin"
)
```

still no joy. Have tried multiple variations of this, but keep getting the same message from the automated build.

So can anyone help with either a) getting the signing tool to be recoginised on the build server or b) getting the automated build to skip the postbuild event?

Comment: are you able to navigate with explorer to the SignTool.exe on your TF Build server?

Comment: @TimVK yes - and if i run the equivalent in a command prompt it works fine

Comment: And if you run the build from TFS with the sign script but without the condition in the postbuild event, cannot you see in the log build `Activity log` where the build was looking for the signtool?

Comment: @TimVK the condition in postbuild event makes no difference - it's getting ignored and same message with or without it. The message in log is (XapPackager target) -> 
  MSBUILD : error : Xap packaging failed. Cannot locate the signing tool SignTool.exe. [C:\Builds\1\Castle\Castle Continuous Integration\Sources\Castle\Castle\Castle.csproj]
Which is the project file in which the post build event is

Comment: And in your project properties, check if the checkbox `Sign the assembly` is not marked. If it is marked, this is causing the error probably. Try following this post http://blogs.infosupport.com/silverlight-4-digitally-signing-a-xap/

Comment: @TimVK Yes - thats one of the articles I followed to get the signing set up in the first place. Sign Assembly checkbox is not checked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26650/discussion-between-timvk-and-stevel)

Comment: @TimVK -Fixed it! Thanks Tim wasn't sign the assembly that was the problem but Sign The Xap File. Your comment got me thinking - why am I specifying it in the Signing tab and in the build events tab. Unchecked it and it works. It must have been doing it twice - once for all builds and once following the conditional statement.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it is solved. It is always good to know the solution after all even if I didn't provided it. You never know when somebody gets to the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem in the end...
I had been putting in place some features so the app would download and install the latest xap file. This requires it to be signed. As this wasn't working I followed some instructions on signing a xap file, not realising that one of the other developers here had put in place the code I described above in the post build event.
I had mistakenly thought that this was created as a result of me checking the 'Sign The Xap File' check box.

So first issue was that other developer had not shared his pfx file with us to add to our certificate stores.
Second, and main issue, was that we then had two attempts at signing going on. The one via the check box and the one via the post build event. I removed the check box and it worked fine.
The issue with the check box is that it expects the SignTool.exe to be in a particular location. On our development boxes with full VS it is where it is looking for it, but on the build server it wasn't. Think it may also have something to do with 64bit machines.
By using only the build event (once you have the correct certificates installed) you can specify explicitly the location that the signtool is going to be, and if necessary install the windows sdk to that location.

Answer (score 0):

This is the top result in Google for this error so updating it with my steps to resolve.

The above didnt work for me but performing the steps below should fix it.

1. Install the Windows 8.1 SDK on the build server (Windows 2008 R2 for me)
2. Adding the Windows SDK BIN directory (that contains signtool.exe, on my server) to the Environment PATH variable - e.g. c:\program files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin - note: Do not add quotes around this
3. Restart all the Visual Studio Team Foundation services in services.msc after you add the file path to the PATH variable as it needs to reload these before building